# How do i access xml namespaces in React jsx

Tags: reactjs, xml, namespaces

I have used xml namespaces in index.html like this.

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

How do i access these attributes in my jsx code? As it says these attributes are undefined.

```
<p class=MsoNormal>
<span class=subheader1>
<span style='font-size:13.0pt'></span>
</span>
<span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need that? but the following might help you:

```
render(){
  return (
    <div attr={document.children[0].attributes['xmlns:w'].value}>
      <div>{document.children[0].attributes['xmlns:o'].value}<div>
    <div>
  )
}
```

`document.children[0]` is the html tag of your current html-page. [I](http://tnickel.de/) hope this is helpful.